Scraping online articles for summary using Python
I am trying to scrape articles from several hyperlinks, get the title of the article & create a summary with the contents of the first 4  paragraphs & save the output in a .png file. But it gives error -
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 70>()
78
79     # Calculate height for summary
---> 80     summary_height = calculate_text_height(draw, summary, font_summary)
81     current_height += summary_height + 30  # 30 pixels spacing after summary
82
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py in getlength(self, text, *args, **kwargs)
203         .. versionadded:: 9.2.0
204         """
--> 205         width, height = self.font.getsize(text)
206         return width
207
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
**
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Function to get title and summary from a URL
def extract_info(url):
    try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8'  # Ensure UTF-8 encoding
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract title
    title = soup.title.string.strip() if soup.title and soup.title.string else 'No Title Found'
    
    # Extract the first 4 paragraphs as summary
    paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    if paragraphs:
        summary_paragraphs = [p.get_text(strip=True) for p in paragraphs[:4] if p.get_text(strip=True)]
        summary = '\n\n'.join(summary_paragraphs) if summary_paragraphs else 'No Summary Found'
    else:
        summary = 'No Summary Found'
    
    return title, summary
except Exception as e:
    return 'Error fetching details', str(e)

# List of URLs
urls = [
     "https://www.cisa.gov/news-events/events",
    "https://www.cisa.gov/news-events/cybersecurity-advisories",
    "https://www.cisa.gov/news-events/alerts/2024/08/14/adobe-releases-security- 
     updates-multiple-products",
    "https://www.youtube.com/@cisagov",
    "https://www.dhs.gov",
    "https://www.kaspersky.com/home-security? 
 icid=gl_securelisheader_acq_ona_smm__onl_b2c_securelist_prodmen_______",
  ]

  # Collect all the data
data = []
for url in urls:
    print(f"Processing URL: {url}")
    title, summary = extract_info(url)
    data.append((title, url, summary))

# Determine the image height dynamically
 width = 1200
 padding = 50  # Padding around text
 current_height = padding

# Use a Unicode-compatible font
try:
   font_path = "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf"  
   font_title = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 24)
   font_url = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 20)
   font_summary = ImageFont.truetype(font_path, 18)
except:
   font_title = ImageFont.load_default()
   font_url = ImageFont.load_default()
   font_summary = ImageFont.load_default()

# Create a dummy image to calculate text size
dummy_img = Image.new('RGB', (width, 1000))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(dummy_img)

def calculate_text_height(draw, text, font):
# Calculate the bounding box of the text and return its height
   bbox = draw.multiline_textbbox((0, 0), text, font=font)
   return bbox[3] - bbox[1]

for title, url, summary in data:
   # Calculate height for title
    title_height = calculate_text_height(draw, title, font_title)
    current_height += title_height + 10  # 10 pixels spacing

 # Calculate height for url
url_height = calculate_text_height(draw, url, font_url)
current_height += url_height + 10

# Calculate height for summary
summary_height = calculate_text_height(draw, summary, font_summary)
current_height += summary_height + 30  # 30 pixels spacing after summary

# Add some bottom padding
current_height += padding

  # Create the final image
image = Image.new('RGB', (width, current_height), color=(255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

y_text = padding
for title, url, summary in data:
    # Draw title
    draw.text((padding, y_text), title, font=font_title, fill="black")
    y_text += calculate_text_height(draw, title, font_title) + 10  # 10 pixels spacing

# Draw URL
draw.text((padding, y_text), url, font=font_url, fill="blue")
y_text += calculate_text_height(draw, url, font_url) + 10

# Draw Summary
draw.multiline_text((padding, y_text), summary, font=font_summary, fill="black", spacing=4)
y_text += calculate_text_height(draw, summary, font_summary) + 30  # 30 pixels spacing after summary

# Save the image in the current working directory
image.save('website_info.png')

# Display the image
image.show()


Please post the full traceback of the error so we can see where it's coming from.

And fix the code indentation. You have except: outside the function definition.

Please post a [mre]. It looks like there's lots of code here that's unrelated to the error. If the error is happening during the scraping, all the display code is probably irrelevant.

What this says is that, somewhere, one of your calls is passing a Unicode string to an API that expects only ASCII characters.  Without the traceback, we can't tell you how to override that.

Seems like that the font library you are using does not support certain Unicode characters, like '\u2019' (right single quotation mark). This commonly occurs when trying to render non-ASCII text with a font that supports only latin-1 encoding. try this maybe you can fix it Ensure you're using a font that supports the full range of Unicode characters. Common fonts that work:

DejaVu Sans (or DejaVu Serif for serif fonts)
Arial Unicode MS
Noto Sans (or Noto Serif for serif fonts)

